How does Google Cloud Translation API works for Document Translation?
So, I am working at a project that translates Legal Documents using a CustomModel from Google. The project only translates texts, but the clients are asking PDF support.
So, I've tested some PDF pages translation in my personal account and I was charges per page, which is how it's suppose to do. Then, I checked the Quotas page and the "v2 and v3 general model characters per day" was showing how much characters I translated.

I asked for Google Cloud Sales Support, but the person doesn't seems the most trustworthy. They say they actually charges per character and per page, but it's not clear in the Google Documentation. That's why I am asking if there's someone who uses this service in large scale.

If it's charge for both, I need to know beforehand the amount of characters from the PDF's files.

Google's Cloud Vision API is specifically designed for extracting text from images and PDFs and is more cost effective text extraction than using Google Translate Advanced.

This doesn't actually answer my question, but I will look into this product. I am focusing into translating editable PDF, not the scanned documents one. And even If I was working with scanned PDFs, I need to rebuild respecting the previous layout.
